# libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB and libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB

Tags: python, opencv, windows-10

I'm trying to make my code resize an image but when I do `cv2.imread('img.png', 1)` it spits out the error
`libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB`
and `libpng warning: iCCP: cHRM chunk does not match sRGB`
here is my full code.

```
img1 = cv2.imread('img1.png', 1)
img2 = cv2.imread('img2.png', 1)
#I dont think anything below is important at all for now.
img1 = cv2.resize(img1, (1024, 1024))
img2 = cv2.resize(img2, (1024, 1024))
```